TinyMCE changes behavior of unrelated ContentEditable
We want to use an inline tinymce alongside a contenteditable div on our page. We just noticed, that tinymce changes the "newline" behavior of an unrelated contenteditable div. Usually pressing enter adds <div> containers to the content editable. However, after adding an inline tinymce to the page, pressing "newline" adds <p> elements.
Example:
https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/HsqIMA6IS3/1
Inline is set to "true" here. If we press "enter" in the content editable (id=notTinymce) we see that <p> elements are added.
https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/HsqIMA6IS3/2
Here, we change inline to "false". This changes the behavior of the content editable div to insert <div> containers instead of <p>
Is there a way to ensure that tinymce is only affecting the element it is supposed to affect? Or those anyone know if this behavior is expected?
Edit: Just realized that the issue is not happening in Firefox. Chromium based browser seem to be affected
